# CMFCTabCtrl ActiveTab on CMDIChildWndEx::OnMDIActivate and the MenuBar issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

As the title propose, I have an `CMDIChildWndEx` application(on VS2017, Windows 10 x64). On the `ChildFrame`, `CMyView` creates: (A) `CMFCTabCtrl` (Id=1), 2 `CView` derived classes: Lets say (B) `CViewDerivedA` object (Id=2) and (C) `CViewDerivedB` object (Id=3). The parent of A-C is the parent of `CMyView`. `CMyView` adds `CDerivedViewA` object as tab-0, and `CViewDerivedB` object as tab-1. `CViewDerivedA` handle MenuA of the menubar . But, when I open a MDI document, the menu is not enabled, until I switch to tab-1 & back to tab-0. I try the following code, but `SetFocus()` doesn't work:

```
// An application sends the WM_MDIACTIVATE message to a multiple-document interface (MDI)
// client window to instruct the client window to activate a different MDI child window.
void CMyChildFrame::OnMDIActivate(BOOL bActivate, CWnd* pActivateWnd, CWnd* pDeactivateWnd)
{
    CMDIChildWndEx::OnMDIActivate(bActivate, pActivateWnd, pDeactivateWnd);

    if (bActivate)
    {
        CMFCTabCtrl *pTabCtrl = (CMFCTabCtrl*) GetDlgItem(1);

        if (pTabCtrl->GetActiveTab() == 0) // 0 - Silhouette tab, 1 - Hit List tab
        {
//          CWnd * pWnd = GetDlgItem(2);
//          pWnd->SetFocus();

            pTabCtrl->SetActiveTab(1);
            pTabCtrl->SetActiveTab(0);
        }
    }
}
```

In any case, this solution seems to me not "clean", a "workaround". >>>> I assume that the proper way is to tell the `pTabCtrl` (Id=1) to `SetFocus()` on the active tab, as it does when I `SetActiveTab()` next & back. What is the way to make it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:

```
void CMyChildFrame::OnMDIActivate(BOOL bActivate, CWnd* pActivateWnd, CWnd* pDeactivateWnd)
    {
        CMDIChildWndEx::OnMDIActivate(bActivate, pActivateWnd, pDeactivateWnd);

        if (bActivate)
        {
            CView * pView = (CView*)((CMFCTabCtrl*)GetDlgItem(1))->GetActiveWnd();
            SetActiveView(pView);
        }
    }
```